# Java:How can I populate map if I use callables?

Tags: java, database, multithreading, concurrency, dictionary

I want to use a `Map` as a form of small database "cache" in my application.
I thought that it would be better to use something like:

`ConcurrentHashMap<K,Callable<V>>`

So that I have a single cache for many kind of database objects (and not 1 for each kind i.e. `` `ConcurrentHashMap<K,V> `` where `V` would be some specific object).

My problem now (assuming all the above thoughts are reasonable) is how would I pre-load this cache on start up from DB?

I mean using callable if I need something in the cache and is not there the callable would get it the first time and have it ready on the next `get`.

But how can I pre-load the cache if I use callables?

Note:I am not interested in using some library since my needs are small.

Comment: I really don't see how you intend to use the callable's here.  Callable is just an interface; what will you do for the implementation?

Comment: I would use a `Callable` as value and if the `key` is not in cache the `callable` would do an sql query to get it the first time.The next queries will be succesful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You *might* have better luck with `ConcurrentHashMap<K, Future<V>>`, since `Future` better matches the concept of "something in the process of being computed, or possibly already computed."  You could just initialize some elements of the cache with a `Future` that's already computed.

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you just do something simple like this?

```
for (Callable<V> c : map.values()) {
    c.call();
}
```

Comment: No because I don't know the key.I have to use the callable to query the DB using the key

Comment: If you had the key, how would you pass it into the callable anyway?

Answer (score 0):

You probably should use interfaces on your objects:

```
public interface Cacheable{}

public MyObject implements Cacheable{...}

ConcurrentHashMap<K, Cacheable> = ...
```

Comment: Not sure how that helps.I would use a Callable as value and if the key is not in cache the callable would do an sql query to get it the first time.The next queries will be succesful.

Comment: @Jim, I really don't understand what you are trying to do - Callable is an interface, can you provide an example on how you'd use that?